# Deploying react in development mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devops

I am working on a project where the schedule forces us to deploy our react app to serve it to the client as fast as possible.

Our production configuration is not ready yet, which makes me wonder whether deploying it in development mode to production has any associated security risks? Or is there just a performance difference?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying an app in development mode your bundle will be heavier (because there is no minification and your `bundle.js.map`). React and some other packages are relying on `process.env.NODE_ENV` to throw error or warning. Your console will propably print a lot of things slowing down (a bit) your application.